# Chapter Caption + Header: How do I recreate this beauty?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, article

I just saw this beautiful caption:

[image: Caption]

And then I saw this beautiful heading:

[image: Header]

The source code is here: https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=http://www.latextemplates.com/templates/books/5/kaobook.zip

My problem is that I am too dumb to see where he sets that heading + how he sets that chapter style. And I don't want to use the entire template (I am creating my own).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[sfdefault,ultralight]{FiraSans} %% option 'sfdefault' activates Fira Sans as the default text font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{{\firaoldstyle #1}}
\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```